# WCF - What is it exactly?

Tags: .net, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740/what-is-wcf)

I am a beginning programmer, and would like to know what WCF actually is.

Maybe this is a stupid question but I can't get it figured out.

I know it's a part of the .NET framework, but is it a way of working? Or is it a piece of code you can implement? or is it an interface?

I understand it is something about working with webservices.

Can anyone explain it to me so it's a bit more clear?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is WCF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740/what-is-wcf) see also [What does WCF mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747691/what-does-wcf-mean)

Comment: Google and MSDN are your friends. It's a communication foundation, means it's low level and allows you to use some base classes or to build yours using what is provided, everything about communications not only web or HTTP based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx

Comment: Yeah, but I when would you use WCF? Or is it something you will ALWAYS use when developing in .NET?

Comment: Please actually read the link provided. Your question shows, you didn't read it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a framework for communication, focussed on communication in service oriented applications, although it can be used for other types of communication as well.

The [MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) article has more info